# How can I sum after convert that from string to int list values?

Tags: list, haskell

I have basic  problem with Haskell but I'm pretty new that's way struggled extremely already
I have got limited knowledge related haskell (before this I did deal with C root with languages)
so far I explaıned myself

Imagine that we have such that list on String format in haskell ["2","76","564"] so I desire to convert Integer [2,76,564] something like that.(I did )

after I need to sum of all list element

2+76+564 = 642 stopped in this part

```
convert::  [String] -> [Int]
convert = map read
convert (xs:x)= x + convert xs
```

How can I calculate after that I convert part.

Answer (score 1):

Your `convert` does not makes much sense: it has two clauses where the first clause has no parameter and the second one has one parameter. It is sufficient to implement `convert` as:

```
convert :: [String] -> [Int]
convert = map read
```

You can then calculate the sum with [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum):

```
convertSum :: [String] -> Int
convertSum = sum . convert
```

We can also implement `convertSum` with recursion in that case it looks like:

```
convertSum :: [String] -> Int
convertSum [] = …
convertSum (x:xs) = read x + …
```

where I leave implementing the `…` parts as an exercise.

Comment: I considered what you said but some points still grey in my mind (not certain) you mentioned unproper func. and unsufficient parameter no problem so far but  calling function part apperently not okay for me https://i.imgur.com/h7pUv4a.png  ---convert.sum-- why I created 3 different function tag ?

Comment: @01d: a function has a signature which is something like `convert :: [String] -> [Int]` that specifies the types of the input and output, and a function implementation, like `convert = map read`. You should *not* implement `sum` that is one that is exposed by the `Prelude`, it is thus a function that you can use.

Comment: as far as convert process not literally convert does not hold integer value in  list , just convert integer. I'm thinking if I hold fully integer I could manipulated easily but I get error message always when I compile.I realized I have  not enough pratice but something standing in my mind still.

Comment: @01d: here `convert` produces a list of `Int`s, hence `[Int]`. `convertSum` on the other hand returns the sum, so an `Int`.